# Can you set a YouTube video's license to CreativeCommons via the PHP 3.0 API?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

You're supposed to be able to do this, through something like this:

```
$snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("some title");
$snippet->setDescription("some description);
...

$status = new Google_VideoStatus();
$status->setPrivacyStatus("public");
$status->setLicense("creativeCommon");

$video = new Google_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);
```

and so on.  Yes, you'd think that the value for setLicense would be "creativeCommons", but it's not (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource).  Using "creativeCommons" or anything other than "youtube" and "creativeCommon" results in a "(500) Bad Request" response.

But the real problem is that, for me anyway, once the video gets up to YouTube (which it is doing), I get a YouTube license regardless of whether I've specified "youtube" or "creativeCommon".  So: is this supposed to work / am I doing it wrong / are there any ideas out there?

Comment: I have noticed the same problem. setPrivacyStatus() seems to work fine, but setLicense(), setEmbeddable(), and setPublicStatsViewable() do not. The API indicates that all 4 should be available when using part = "status". There does not seem to be any further discussion or explanation about this anywhere. Does anyone know the trick to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone but (a few years later) it seems to work to set the licencetype to creativeCommon using the javascript-version of the api (v3).

```
UploadVideo.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
    var metadata = {
        status: {
            privacyStatus: $('#privacy-status option:selected').text(),
            license: "creativeCommon"
        }
    };
```